# How to remove all alphanumeric words from the text?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm trying to write regular expression in PHP which simply would **remove alphanumeric words (words which contains digits)**, but not numbers which have [punctuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punctuation) and similar special characters (e.g. prices, phone numbers, etc.).

Words which should be removed:

> `1st`, `H20`, `2nd`, `O2`, `3rd`, `NUMB3RS`, `Rüthen1`, `Wrocław2`

Words which shouldn't be removed:

> `0`, `5.5`, `10`, `$100`, `£65`, `+44`, `(20)`, `123`, `ext:124`, `4.4-BSD`,

Here is the code so far:

```
$text = 'To remove: 1st H20; 2nd O2; 3rd NUMB3RS; To leave: Digits: -2 0 5.5 10, Prices: $100 or £65, Phone: +44 (20) 123 ext:124, 4.4-BSD';
$pattern = '/\b\w*\d\w*\b-?/';
echo $text, preg_replace($pattern, " ", $text);
```

However it removes all words including digits, prices and phone.

I've also tried so far the following patterns:

```
/(\\s+\\w{1,2}(?=\\W+))|(\\s+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\\d+)/ # Removes digits, etc.
/[^(\w|\d|\'|\"|\.|\!|\?|;|,|\\|\/|\-|:|\&|@)]+/ # Doesn't work.
/(\\s+\\w{1,2}(?=\\W+))|(\\s+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\\d+)/ # Removes too much.
/[^\p{L}\p{N}-]+/u                       # It removes only special characters.
/(^[\D]+\s|\s[\D]+\s|\s[\D]+$|^[\D]+$)+/ # Removes words.
/ ?\b[^ ]*[0-9][^ ]*\b/i                 # Almost, but removes digits, price, phone.
/\s+[\w-]*\d[\w-]*|[\w-]*\d[\w-]*\s*/    # Almost, but removes digits, price, phone.
/\b\w*\d\w*\b-?/                         # Almost, but removes digits, price, phone.
/[A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*/       # Almost, but removes too much.
```

which I've found across SO (most of them are usually too specific) and other sites which suppose to remove words with digits, but they're not.

How I can write a simple regular expression which can remove these words without touching other things?

Sample text:

> To remove: `1st` `H20`; `2nd` `O2`; `3rd` `NUMB3RS`;
>
> To leave: Digits: -2 0 5.5 10, Prices: $100 or £65, Phone: +44 (20) 123 ext:124, 4.4-BSD

Expected output:

> To remove:    ;    ;    ; To leave: Digits: -2 0 5.5 10, Prices: $100 or £65, Phone: +44 (20) 123 ext:124, 4.4-BSD

Comment: I would do a split on spaces to get an array of words, then check each word with number to see if it contains special characters, and if so remove from array, then implode the array with space as glue.  Its not regex but it would be easier to get right.

Comment: What is you expected input and output? Can you give a short example?

Comment: @hek2mgl I've added expected output.

Comment: You need to (precisely) define what you mean by: _"special characters"_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about replacing `\b(?=[a-z]+\d|[a-z]*\d+[a-z]+)\w*\b\s*` with nothing?

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/jA2fW3/1

Pattern code:

```
$pattern = '/\b(?=[a-z]+\d|[a-z]*\d+[a-z]+)\w*\b\s*/i';
```

To match alphanumeric words containing foreign/accented letters, use the following pattern:

```
$pattern = '/\b(?=[\pL]+\d|[\pL]*\d+[\pL]+)[\pL\w]*\b\s*/i';
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/jA2fW3/3

Comment: Work perfectly, however words such as `Rüthen1`, `Wrocław2` are removed in half. I know it wasn't predicted in the description, but it's nice to have. I've tried to add `u` modifier for Unicode, but doesn't work as expected. I'll try to look for some solution.

Comment: I've tried to replace all instances of `a-z` with `\p{L}` (to match any kind of letter from any language), but it seems it doesn't work properly, however this method works in hwnd's example.

Comment: @kenorb Glad you got it working, though I was able to make mine work https://regex101.com/r/jA2fW3/3.

Answer (score 3):

You can modify your regular expression as follows for the desired output.

```
$text = preg_replace('/\b(?:[a-z]+\d+[a-z]*|\d+[a-z]+)\b/i', '', $text);
```

To match any kind of letter from any language, use the Unicode property `\p{L}`:

```
$text = preg_replace('/\b(?:\pL+\d+\pL*|\d+\pL+)\b/u', '', $text);
```